# Optional parameter in enum case in swift

Tags: swift, enums

In swift a function can have a optional parameters that have default values such as:

```
func f(a:Int, b:Int?=nil) {}

f(1);
f(1,2);
```

I'd like to do this with associated values with an enum. Following from this post  about [type safe url routes](http://chris.eidhof.nl/posts/typesafe-url-routes-in-swift.html), I'd like to have a route which can take an optional parameter, such as:

```
enum StopPoint {
    case Search(query:String, limit:Int?=nil)
}
```

However it says I can't have an default value for a parameter in a tuple. However it is possible to have a case such as `case Arrivals(stopId:Int)`, yet it is not possible in general to have a tuple with one named parameter.

So is it possible to have an enum with a default parameter, and is the associated value a tuple or not?

Comment: seems like it works in Swift 5:
`case provisioning(String, isNewLine: Bool = true)` works for me. I can use it like `.provisioning("single argument")`

Comment: @oluckyman indeed it does.

Answer (score 14):

What you can do is:

```
enum StopPoint {
    case Search(query: String, limit: Int?)

    init(query: String, limit: Int? = nil) {
        self = .Search(query: query, limit: limit)
    }
}

let foo = StopPoint(query: "default")             // Search("default", nil)
let bar = StopPoint(query: "special", limit:  42) // Search("special", Optional(42))
```

Comment: There would be other cases than just search.

Answer (score 14):

You can do this by creating static functions on the enum that matches the enum case that you want to allow optional parameters for.

```
enum StopPoint {
    case search(query: String, limit: Int?)

    static func search(query: String) -> StopPoint {
        return .search(query: query, limit: nil)
    }
}
```

This makes it so that you can both provide the limit, or not, using the expected syntax:

```
let a = StopPoint.search(query: "Foobar")
let b = StopPoint.search(query: "Foobar", limit: 5)
let c = StopPoint.search(query: "Foobar", limit: nil)

func foo(_ stop: StopPoint) { /* ... */ }

foo(.search(query: "Foobar"))
foo(.search(query: "Foobar", limit: 5))
foo(.search(query: "Foobar", limit: nil))
```

Tested and confirmed working with Swift 4.2

Answer (score 5):

I do not think that is possible. It is simply a neat feature of `function`s. Nothing that the actual tuple underneath supports. The docs for [*Default Parameter Values*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) state:

> You can define a default value for any parameter in a function by assigning a value to the parameter after that parameter’s type. If a default value is defined, you can omit that parameter when calling the function.

Enums simply do not to have that feature. You have to explicitly use a different enum element for including optional additional parameters:

```
enum StopPoint {
    case Search(String)
    case SearchLimit(String, Int)
}
```

Enums are quite powerful but not thaaaat powerful. You cannot use default values, you can for example not use a variadic type (maybe even more *"restrictions"*):

```
enum StopPoint {
    case SearchMult(String...) // causes compile error
}
```

As to the potentially interesting of the *"why"*-question: no idea, I am not that deeply involved in the language architecture.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you have already considered this and discounted it: You can come close to the convenience of what you are looking for by creating a static func on the enum:

```
enum StopPoint {
    case Search(query:String, limit:Int?)

    static func createSearch(query:String, limit:Int?=nil) -> StopPoint {
        return .Search(query: query, limit: limit)
    }
}

let myStopPoint = StopPoint.createSearch("my query")
```